# Can we use Phonegap with Java for Android

Tags: android, cordova

Normally, we build native Android applications via Java.
Now, we also have Phonegap which can be used to build apps. 
However, can we combine both of them so that some functions which cannot be called using html, css and javascript can be used through PhoneGap.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah you can do that by using or writing your own Phonegap Plugin.
Check the documentation for Phonegap Plugins.

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it by creating a plugin for phonegap. By communicating with your plugin you will be able  to run your Java code.

A good tutorial on how to build a plugin for phonegap/android can be found here:
http://phpmyweb.net/2011/09/14/creating-a-plugin-for-phonegap-1-0-android/